# Unable to find this module in its module map : Picker.android.js : (This is from react native )

Tags: react-native, react-redux

Thanks in advance;
while I run-android using react native am getting these error.
I've already cleared the cache and added the node modules after removing.
Is there any work around.

Answer (score 0):

I got my issued fixed by install the react native device info and setting the link.